# Why does turning my kitchen light off turn on my outside light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

when I turn my fluorescent kitchen light off, my outside p.i.r security light comes on, why? the problem started when my father moved the p.i.r up above the door

Comment: Does this happen during daylight hours?  Or only at night?

Comment: Is the kitchen light controlled by more than one switch? Sounds like the outdoor light was connected to one of the 3-way switch travelers.

Comment: Is the sensor for the security light within line of sight of the kitchen light??

Comment: wallyk- it happens at night

Comment: bcworkz- no the kitchen light is on one switch

Comment: bib- yes it is since my dad moved it

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the sensor on your light might be aimed incorrectly. It could be that it is sensing the movement in your kitchen, and when the kitchen light is turned it becomes dark enough for the light to activate. Try adjusting where the sensor is pointing and see if that helps at all.